# Go not finding local modules

Tags: go, module, local

trying to follow the examples in the Go tutorial. Trying to export a function called VerifyConnection from a module called functions2, into my main module called test-db-connection.

I've followed the directions explicitly, the module with my functions should be example.com/functions2

The 'replace' directive looks correct, however when I try to build I get the following:

```
# example.com/test-db-connection2
.\main.go:8:5: "example.com/functions2" imported and not used
.\main.go:17:16: undefined: VerifyConnection
```

It is "as if" the replace directive isn't working, it doesn't seem to recognize my local module.

What am I doing wrong?

Tried this twice starting from scratch, same symptom both times.

Edit: the short answer to this question seems to be, Go will not work at all in any directory other than the one GOPATH is pointing to. I was able to get this to work by placing my entire directory tree in the GOPATH, and renaming "myproject" to example.com - so my actual path is now $GOPATH/example.com/module1 and so on. GO doesn't seem to find the module unless it's in the exact right place "relative to the GOPATH". I'm not sure why they do things this way, it seems kind of primitive. Mainly though, the documentation doesn't make this clear, and Go installs everything on the system drive and most people don't want to to development there, the first thing people are going to do is try this on a different drive, and it won't work. Unless you set up the GOPATH correctly first. I guess with that, this question is closeable, just wanted to add this information.

Comment: Can you show us the layout of the code? Something like the output of `tree` or `find . -type f` would be helpful. Also the contents of your `go.mod` file.

Comment: Just a comment on your additions - Your main issue is that you are using GOPATH; [modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules) were introduced four years ago and you should be using them (run `go mod init`) unless you have a very good reason for using GOPATH (I cannot think of one :-) ). See the main [go tutorial](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

What is the package name?
If it is functions2, Seems the import is okay, but you have to call the functions like `functions2.VerifyConnection()`

Thats why you got the error, import is not used.
Make sure you have correct path for this import, in your source directory,

```
go_workspace/
├── src/
│   └── example.com/
│       └── functions2/
│           └── someconn.go <this will have your VerifyConnection()
└── bin/
```

Now your code someconn.go should have the ConnctionVerify somethign like below

```
package functions2

import "fmt"

func VefifyConnection() {
    fmt.Println("Welcome to the functions2 package!")
}
```

Now from main.go you could try something like below,

```
package main

import (
    "example.com/functions2"
)

func main() {
    functions2.VerifyConnection()
}
```

Then build your code, will work as expected